# How to get a likelihood using Mixture of Gaussian Model

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, gaussian, mixture-model

To simplify my question, I create a dummy problem here: I have two sets of training data that are labelled with 1 and 2 respectively. Both training datasets assumed to follow mixture of Gaussian distribution. I can easily use Matlab toolbox function (gmdistribution.fit) to estimate their mean and covariance.

Then I have some testing dataset that assumed to be created with an MoG similar to training dataset 2, but with noise. I would like to calculate something like a likelihood probability that my testing dataset is more likely to be generated using the MoG of training dataset 2. In other words, I would like to get the likelihood of my testing dataset to have the label 2.

Could you please point a direction how to do this? Thanks very much.

N.B.:

1. The **sizes** of my two training datasets are **different**.
2. The distributions of the two training datasets are **overlapped**.
3. The size of the testing dataset is much **smaller** than the training datasets.

Some Matlab codes:

```
%% Mixture of Gassian 1 (Training set 1)
mean1                                   = [1 -2];
cov1                                    = [2 0; 0 .5];
mean2                                   = [0.5 -5];
cov2                                    = [1 0; 0 1];
trainingDataset1                        = [mvnrnd(mean1, cov1, 1000); mvnrnd(mean2, cov2, 1000)];

MoGOptions                              = statset('Display', 'final');
MoGObj1                                 = gmdistribution.fit(trainingDataset1, 2, 'Options', MoGOptions);

figure,
scatter(trainingDataset1(:,1), trainingDataset1(:,2), 10, '.')
hold on
ezcontour(@(x,y)pdf(MoGObj1,[x y]), [-8 6], [-8 2]);

%% Mixture of Gassian 2 (Training set 2)
mean4                                   = [0.5 -1];
cov4                                    = [1.5 0; 0 .8];
mean5                                   = [-2 -3];
cov5                                    = [1 0; 0 1];
mean6                                   = [-4 -2];
cov6                                    = [1 0; 0 1];
trainingDataset2                        = [mvnrnd(mean4, cov4, 500); mvnrnd(mean5, cov5, 500); mvnrnd(mean6, cov6, 500)];

MoGOptions                              = statset('Display', 'final');
MoGObj2                                 = gmdistribution.fit(trainingDataset2, 2, 'Options', MoGOptions);

figure,
scatter(trainingDataset2(:,1), trainingDataset2(:,2), 10, '.')
hold on
ezcontour(@(x,y)pdf(MoGObj2,[x y]), [-8 6], [-8 2]);

%% Test set
mean7                                   = [1.1 -2.1];
cov7                                    = [2.2 0; 0 .4];
mean8                                   = [0.3 -5.4];
cov8                                    = [1.2 0; 0 1.1];
testingDataset1                         = [mvnrnd(mean7, cov7, 100); mvnrnd(mean8, cov8, 100)];

figure,
scatter(testingDataset1(:,1), testingDataset1(:,2), 10, '.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I find AIC and BIC to be very convenient.

try "struct(MoGObj2)" to get an ideal of the fields in your fit.

One of them is NLogL which is negative of log-likelihood.  I think this is what you are looking for.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistributionclass.html

Best of luck